# How to Add Instance Variable of Type Some Class to Another Class. In the Context of Model View

Tags: javascript

I need to connect the view to the model.

How do I add an instance variable of type `Calc` to the `CalcFrame` class, called `theCalc`, then in the constructor create an instance of the `Calc` class and assign `theCalc` variable to reference it.

This is my first time using Stack overflow, so, I am not sure if these are the exact questions to ask.

This is the model:

```
public class Calc {

    private double input1;
    private double input2;
    private double output1;

    public double getInput1() {
        return input1;
    }
    public double getInput2() {
        return input2;
    }
    public double getOutput1() {
        return output1;
    }
    public void setInput1(double input) {
        input1 = input;
    }
    public void setInput2(double input) {
        input2 = input;
    }
    public void setOuput1(double output) {
        output1 = output;
    }
    public void add() {
        output1 = input1 + input2;
    }
    public void subtract() {
        output1 = input1 - input2;
    }
    public void multiply() {
        output1 = input1 * input2;
    }
    public void divide() {
        output1 = input1/input2;
    }
}
```

This is where I think I need to add the instance variable of type `Calc`:

```
public class CalcFrame extends JFrame {

    private JTextField input1;
    private JTextField input2;
    private JTextField output1;
    private JButton add;
    private JButton subtract;
    private JButton multiply;
    private JButton divide; 
    private Calc theCalc;

    private class ActionAdd implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            theCalc.setInput1(Double.parseDouble(input1.getText()));
            theCalc.setInput2(Double.parseDouble(input2.getText()));
            theCalc.add();
            output1.setText(String.valueOf(theCalc.getOutput1()));
        }
    }
    private class ActionSubtract implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    }
    private class ActionMultiply implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    }
    private class ActionDivide implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    }
    public CalcFrame() {
        super();
        theCalc = new Calc(); // I believe this is the theCalc variable to reference the instance of the Calc class
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        input1 = new JTextField(10);
        input2 = new JTextField(10);
        JPanel inPanel = new JPanel();
        inPanel.add(input1);
        inPanel.add(input2);
        contentPane.add(inPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        output1 = new JTextField(10);
        contentPane.add(output1,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add = new JButton("+");
        add.addActionListener(new ActionAdd());
        subtract = new JButton("-");
        subtract.addActionListener(new ActionSubtract());
        multiply = new JButton("*");
        multiply.addActionListener(new ActionMultiply());
        divide = new JButton("/");
        divide.addActionListener(new ActionDivide());
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(add);
        buttonPanel.add(subtract);
        buttonPanel.add(multiply);
        buttonPanel.add(divide);
        contentPane.add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
    public CalcFrame(String title) {
        this();
        setTitle(title);
    }
}
```